# Feature name Microsoft-Hyper-V is unknown

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtualización, windows11

estoy tratando de instalar Hyper en windows 11 home pero no logro poder hacerlo.

En las caracteristicas de windows no me muestra la opcion de Hyper

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

busque información y segun veo que viene por defecto de profesional y enterprice pero en el home no,segui buscando información y veo que ejecutan un archivo bat con el siguiente codigo

```
pushd “%~dp0” 
dir /b %SystemRoot%
ervicing\Packages\*Hyper-V*.mum >hv.txt
for /f %%i in (‘findstr /i . hv.txt 2^>nul’) do dism /online /norestart /add- 
package:”%SystemRoot%
ervicing\Packages\%%i”
del hv.txt
Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Hyper-V -All /LimitAccess /ALL
pause
```

ejecute el comando pero me retorna el siguiente error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me puse a revisar si talvez es porque en la bios no esta activada la virtualización pero segun veo que si
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

busque información del error y veo que se ejecuta un comando en powershell

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All
```

pero igual, sigue sin poderme salir la opción de hyper en las caracteristicas de windows